# Improve scaled Image aliasing in Canvas

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I improving the aliasing of `Image` objects painted on a scaled `Canvas`? For example, for the following:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final image = await loadUiImage("assets/thierry.png");

  runApp(MyApp(image));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ui.Image image;

  const MyApp(this.image, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CanvasPainter(this.image),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class CanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  CanvasPainter(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(size.width / image.width);

    canvas.drawImage(
        image,
        Offset.zero,
        ui.Paint()
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..filterQuality = ui.FilterQuality.high);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CanvasPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

This is what I see in the emulator:

[image]

If I scale the image in an image viewer to similar dimensions, I see this:

[image]

The original image is 5814 x 3828.

Notice that the long horizontal lines are more aliased in the version displayed on the emulator. If I don't scale, I don't see this level of aliasing.

Comment: I had tried that for my actual code, but I didn't see any difference there or in this example. I've updated the code to use `FilterQuality.high`

Comment: Hmm, it seems like using `FilterQuality.medium` results in better quality than using `high`. Let me see if this fixes the issue in my actual code.

Comment: Without scaling the problem doesn't happen. According to [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FilterQuality.html), "when scaling down, medium provides the best quality especially when scaling an image to less than half its size". In my case the scale factor is much less than half, so that explains why quality is better with medium.

Comment: The image quality isn't better if you use just `drawImageRect` without `scale`. You need `FilterQuality.medium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the best image quality for my scenario, I had to use `filterQuality = ui.FilterQuality.medium`. According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FilterQuality.html), "when scaling down, medium provides the best quality especially when scaling an image to less than half its size". In my case the scale factor is less than half, so that explains why quality is better with `medium`.

For reference, here's what the above image looks like with `medium`:
[image]